# Colors set in fragment shader not showing GLSL 1.30

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, glsl, shader

I'm learning OpenGL, and I just saw how to write shaders. But the first problem was that, in the course, GLSL 3.30+ was supported (OpenGL 4), but my drivers (mesa) don't allow me to use versions above GLSL 1.30 or ES 3.20. So I changed the `#version` preprocessor in the shaders, and I continued. But, unfortunately, when I tried to use colors, it didn't work.

This is my code :

```
#include "colors.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <regex>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

unsigned int CompileShader(unsigned int type, std::string& source);
unsigned int CreateShader(std::string& vertexShader, std::string& fragmentShader);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    GLFWwindow* window;

    /* Initialize the library */
    if (!glfwInit()) {
        std::cerr << "Couldn't initialize GLFW" << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", nullptr, nullptr);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    /* Make the window's context current */
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    if(glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
        std::cerr << "Couldn't initialize GLEW" << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    float positions[6] = {
        -0.5f, -0.5f,
        0.0f, 0.5f,
        0.5f, -0.5f
    };
    unsigned int buffer;

    glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 6 * sizeof(float), positions, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 2 * sizeof(float), 0);

    // Compiling Shader
    std::string vertexShader = "#version 130\n"
                               "\n"
                               "in vec4 position;\n"
                               "\n"
                               "void main () {\n"
                               "    gl_Position = position;\n"
                               "}";
    std::string fragmentShader = "#version 130\n"
                                 "\n"
                                 "uniform vec4 color = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);\n"
                                 "\n"
                                 "out vec4 outputF;\n"
                                 "\n"
                                 "void main () {\n"
                                 "    outputF = color;\n"
                                 "}";

    unsigned int shader = CreateShader(vertexShader, fragmentShader);

    glUseProgram(shader);

    /* Loop until the user closes the window */
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        /* Render here */
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

        /* Swap front and back buffers */
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        /* Poll for and process events */
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}

unsigned int CompileShader(unsigned int type, std::string& source) {
    unsigned int id = glCreateShader(type);
    const char* src = source.c_str();

    glShaderSource(id, 1, &src, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(id);

    int result;
    glGetShaderiv(id, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &result);

    if (result == GL_FALSE) {
        int length;
        glGetShaderiv(id, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &length);

        char* message = (char*)alloca(length * sizeof(char));
        glGetShaderInfoLog(id, length, &length, message);

        std::cerr << "Failed to compile "
                  << (type == GL_VERTEX_SHADER ? "vertex" : "fragment")
                  << " shader. Error message:" << std::endl;

        std::cerr << "\t" << FG_ERROR << message << std::endl;
    }

    return id;
}

unsigned int CreateShader(std::string& vertexShader, std::string& fragmentShader) {
    unsigned int program = glCreateProgram();
    unsigned int vs = CompileShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShader);
    unsigned int fs = CompileShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShader);

    glAttachShader(program, vs);
    glAttachShader(program, vs);

    glLinkProgram(program);
    glValidateProgram(program);

    glDeleteShader(vs);
    glDeleteShader(fs);

    return program;
}
```

Comment: "my drivers (mesa) don't allow me to use versions above GLSL 1.30 or ES 3.20."  They most likely do, you have to request a versioned Core context though.

Comment: And if they don't, you probably need to assign your result to `gl_FragColor` instead of your custom `out outputF` variable.

Comment: @NicoSchertler The GLSL 1.3 doc says it added user defined outs for the fragment processor even though I think that might fix the issue: https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.1.30.pdf

Comment: @dmoody256 Ah, ok. I was trying to find when this was introduced.

Comment: @dmoody256 In which section is this explained ? Because I don't really understand what you mean by *user defined outs*...

Comment: @PrograMedIP near the bottom of page 4, it says ```Added user-defined fragment shader outputs.```. It's also referenced in other various places through the document.

Comment: @dmoody256 But I still can't find how to fix the issue...

Comment: @PrograMedIP yeah I reproduced the issue with your example on Ubuntu 14, but that was in a virtual box VM so I don't know for sure if the virtual box was causing issues or the mesa drivers themselves. Possibly mesa drivers are not supporting this, but that seems like a pretty basic thing to be missing. Btw can you add what color you saw on your triangle? I saw white triangle with cpu rendering enabled, and black triangle with Virtual Box hardware pass through options. Have you tested on different driver to make sure your code is working as expected in a different environment?

Comment: @dmoody256 It's rendering a white triangle, and I didn't test it yet on other drivers; the AMD GPU drivers don't want to work on my Kali system, and I didn't test it yet on my Windows, but I'm pretty sure that the OpenGL version there is the latest, so I won't have to use old versions of OpenGL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got some time to look at this and found that you had a small copy paste error:

```cpp
unsigned int CreateShader(std::string& vertexShader, std::string& fragmentShader) {
    unsigned int program = glCreateProgram();
    unsigned int vs = CompileShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShader);
    unsigned int fs = CompileShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShader);

    glAttachShader(program, vs);
    glAttachShader(program, vs); //<--should be fs
```

You are attaching the vertex shader twice. This will set an OpenGL error and actually the way I found it is with a OpenGL debugging method I usually use. When I went to test your code more in depth, I surrounded all OpenGL calls with a define which stops execution if OpenGL sets an error. I put this at the top of the source and recommend using this:

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

void CheckOpenGLError(const char *stmt, const char *fname, int line);
#define GL_CHECK(stmt)                               \
    do                                               \
    {                                                \
        stmt;                                        \
        CheckOpenGLError(#stmt, __FILE__, __LINE__); \
    } while (0)

void CheckOpenGLError(const char *stmt, const char *fname, int line)
{
    GLenum err = glGetError();
    if (err != GL_NO_ERROR)
    {
        std::cout << "OpenGL error 0x" << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(8) << std::hex << err << std::dec << ": " << gluErrorString(err) << ", at " << fname << ":" << line << " - for " << stmt << std::endl;
        abort();
    }
}
```

You will need to additionally link in the glu library (glu32.lib on windows or libGLU.so on linux) for the gluErrorString function if you want the OpenGL error to print out in a human readable form, otherwise you need to go look up the error code. In this case I surrounded your calls like this:

```cpp
unsigned int CreateShader(std::string& vertexShader, std::string& fragmentShader) {
    unsigned int program = glCreateProgram();
    unsigned int vs = CompileShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShader);
    unsigned int fs = CompileShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShader);

    GL_CHECK(glAttachShader(program, vs));
    GL_CHECK(glAttachShader(program, vs)); //<--should be fs
```

Which then threw this error when I ran the code:

```
OpenGL error 0x00000502: invalid operation, at main.cpp:147 - for glAttachShader(program, vs)
```

---

Also a minor note, you should probably detach the shaders after you are done linking:

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/47912

```cpp
unsigned int CreateShader(std::string& vertexShader, std::string& fragmentShader) {
    unsigned int program = glCreateProgram();
    unsigned int vs = CompileShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShader);
    unsigned int fs = CompileShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShader);

    glAttachShader(program, vs);
    glAttachShader(program, fs);

    glLinkProgram(program);
    glValidateProgram(program);

    glDetachShader(program, vs);
    glDetachShader(program, fs);

    glDeleteShader(vs);
    glDeleteShader(fs);

    return program;
}
```